# Service worker fetch event passing in wrong type

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I add a fetch event listener like this

```
self.addEventListener( 'fetch', fetch )
```

and here is my fetch function

```
const fetch = e => {
    console.log({e})
    if ( !e.request.url.startsWith( self.location.origin ) || e.request.method !== 'GET' ) return

    const save = async res => {
        const cache = await caches.open( dynamic )
        cache.put( e.request, res )
    }

    const process = async cached => {
        if ( cached ) return cached
        const res = await fetch( e.request.clone() )
        if ( res ) await save( res.clone() )
        return res
    }

    e.respondWith( caches.match( e.request ).then( process ))
}
```

When I look at the event thats being passed in, I expect a fetch event but this is what I see

[image: console log]

Its printing a request object after the correct Fetch event. When i try to access the url, it will of course throw an error as it will effectively be doing request.request.url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `process` method, you're calling the `fetch` function using a cloned Request, which is probably the `Request` you see in your console.

```
const res = await fetch( e.request.clone() )
```

This issue is because your custom method is called `fetch`, but in this case you probably want to use the native `fetch` method. Perhaps you should consider renaming your custom method to prevent conflicts like this.

Comment: ahh of course, thankyou so much

Comment: You're welcome :) Please consider upvoting/accepting my answer if you found it helpful :D